# Problems with MessageBox.Show()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, messagebox

I'm new to code and most things work, but I can't get this code to run. Can someone help?

I tried `using System.Forms` but it showed as missing a namespace. When I used `using System.Windows.Forms` that message went away. It does not let me use both.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"file.csv");
            // for set encoding
            // StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"file.csv", Encoding.GetEncoding(1250));

            string strline = "";
            String[] _values = null;
            int x = 0;
            while(!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                strline = sr.ReadLine();
                _values = strline.Split(',');
                if (_values.Length >= 6 && _values[0].Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.show(_values[1]);
                }
            }
            sr.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jamiec: I am sorry. I have deleted the comment. There is so much more to learn :)

Comment: This really could have been solve with 5 minutes with the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such namespace `System.Forms`, the class you were trying to use (`MessageBox`) is in `System.Windows.Forms`. By correcting your `using` statement, the error went away.

Remember, you must have a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in your console app to use this class.

Answer (score 5):

You need to reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in your project. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DisplayConfirmation_.aspx) is a detailed instruction how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such namespace as *System.Forms* there is only a namespace called *System.Windows.Forms*, wich has the `MessageBox` class you are talking about. To be able to use it, you need to add a reference to the *System.Windows.Forms.dll* to to your project (find it in the .NET Tab in the "Add Reference ..." dialog) and it will work. Also note that `MessageBox.Show()` requires a capital 'S'. Please see below an optimized and fully working version of your code.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"file.csv"))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    string strline = sr.ReadLine();
                    string[] values = strline.Split(',');
                    if (values.Length >= 6 && values[0].Trim().Length > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(values[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You try use it in Console application first you should add `System.Windows.Forms` dll in your references (from .Net reference tab) then use it by adding it's namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused here. there is no namespace called `System.Forms`. It's always `System.Windows.Forms`. And the MessageBox class is defined in `System.Windows.Forms`

You need to manually ADD a reference to your project for `System.Windows.Forms` as you are on a console application and not a Windows Application. Just add the reference.